# Laravel how to sum carbon now with date input in a blade file

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am trying to sum Carbon\Carbon::now() in blade with a date input from database in a blade file.

My code is:

```
{{Carbon\Carbon::now()   +  $uses2->data2pasaport }}
```

But it returns this error:

```
Unsupported operand types: Carbon\Carbon + string
```

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: oh... how do I do that?

Comment: What do you expect from adding two dates? 2022-01-01 + 2022-01-02 does not sound like it makes any sense. 
Can you explain what you are trying to archive?

Comment: avoid any logic in blade.

Comment: If the db date is 2022-08-02 and carbon::now() is 2022-08-01 I want the function to return 1, because it's only a one day difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find time difference between two dates you can use `diffInDays` like:

```
$date = Carbon::parse($uses2->data2pasaport);
$now = Carbon::now();

$diff = $date->diffInDays($now); // difference between dates with days
```

Comment: I did it like: {{   Carbon\Carbon::now() -   Carbon\Carbon::parse($uses2->data2pasaport) }}      and now I get this error                                                                                          Unsupported operand types: Carbon\Carbon - Carbon\Carbon

Comment: What you are actually trying to do? DO you want to add some days or month to date? I need to know what is your `$uses2->data2pasaport` returns?

Comment: $uses2->data2pasaport represents the expiry date of the passport, it returns 2025-06-10, and I want to see how many days are left between the expiry date and todays date

Comment: Please check edited answer. Is that what you need?

Comment: Glad to help you)